# Neither before a plural or singular noun?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Below is a short passage from Harvard Law Review, Volume 66:

> However, with lower courts free to exercise their discretion, there is
>   danger that they may in the same litigation reach opposite conclusions
>   with the result that **neither, or perhaps both, actions** would be stayed
>   or enjoined.

I am wondering if the writer has made a mistake in using "actions" instead of "action" after "neither". Is it because of "or perhaps both"? As far as I know, "neither" is used before a singular noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a (small) point. It is small because the meaning is absolutely clear. It is a point because, if that passage were to be read in isolation, then "...neither action, or perhaps both, would be..." would be logically more correct.